# How to manage the creation of instances when navigating

Tags: mvvm, navigation, windows-phone-7.1

I am programming WP7 application adhering the MVVM pattern.

I have ViewModelLocator which ensures that each instance of ViewModel is only one. These ViewModels are created when application is launched. ViewModels communicating with each other using messages. I use messages for navigatig to next Page (For this I am using NavigationService.Navigate(), which is Raised from MainPage CodeBehind - it is the only functionality that is in CodeBehind ). View and ViewModels are connected together by setting the DataContext in the Page to ViewModelLocator.

Everythig works at first sight.

But during each navigation, there is created new Page instance, which is connected to the ViewModel from ViewModelLocator(which is designed for it). The result is that: when a user often switches between pages, there are multiple instances of a page connected to one ViewModel. Of course, there is visible only one page at one point.

Very simple solution could be setting NavigationCache, but it is readonly in WP7.

I am looking for solution of unwanted behavior.

Comment: In the page unload function try to set the DataContext to Null and then GC will collect the pages more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you Navigate somewhere a new instance is created for that page.
You could avoid this by using NavigationService.GoBack(); where ever you can.

You should also unregister from every event when navigating away from the page, so that way the garbage collector can clear out that page.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to declare an instance of your ViewModel at App.xaml.cs, such as,

```
private static YourViewModel viewModel = null;
public static YourViewModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
        if (viewModel == null)
            viewModel = ViewModelLocator.MainStatic;

        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

Then from the page you will navigate to, you can reference it as App.ViewModel.

If your page is in different assembly form your main application, you could declare following in your App.xaml,

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="VMLocator" />
```

Where vm referencing to your main app, then you can use is as following,

```
((ViewModelLocator)Application.Current.Resources["VMLocator"]).YourViewModel;
```

Hope it would help.